# How to export (copy) a Grafana query

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I'm using grafana to query elasticsearch for plotting some charts. Now, i would like to replicate the same charts in my website, and to do so I've to query elastic on my code and then plot the chart.

Since the query will be the same as the one created with grafana, is there a way to know (and thus copy) the query that grafana generates for plotting the chart?
If i check the exporting of the chart it seems more a grafana syntaxt than an elastic query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the Grafana web page opened, launch the developer tools of the specific browser you are using (F12 in Chrome).

In the network section, you will see the queries Grafana calls when it refreshes its charts.

You can look at the "_msearch" requests, and in the "payload" section you will see the exact elasticsearch query its using.